# Where is the default NSS database used by Dart pub found on OSX?

Tags: ssl, dart, nss

Where is the default NSS database used by dart, particularly pub on OS X? Is it possible to add a root CA to that database?

Comment: I have not much knowledge about how to use certificates in Dart. There are several questions and answers  how to use them here on SO. Currently the Dart team is working on switching to BoringSSL.